# force directed layout fetching specific data from external / internal data links

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I am new to d3js. I am trying to edit the Force directed layout of http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292

when i mouseover to the node circles the corresponding source value filenames should appears as tooltip in div tag. i have almost done and working but fetching the filename returns wrong.

can anyone help me where i went wrong?

i have placed my code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nDEhL

Example:

when i mouseover the **node D** it should return the filename as 'originalfile_c01.txt|originalfile_c04.txt|originalfile_c05.txt' in div tag tooltip

am fetching data links of filename through the mouseover event (click).

I guess below fetching code is wrong?

```
links[a.index].filename;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

created an empty dataset in json and its working good.